# Pandas Python How to make 2 values with equal len?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, pandas-loc

Hi anyone can help on this? i got error when i run this:

```
conditions5 = [
    (data1['Payment Mode'] == '03')
]

choices5 = data1['Value Date']

data1['Valid From Date'] = np.select(conditions5, choices5, default ='') 
data1
```

Error:
List of cases must be same length as list of conditions

I already tried using loc but the same error happen. How can i fix this?

```
data1.loc[data1['Payment Mode'] == '03'] = data1['Value Date']
```

Error:
Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Answer (score 0):

Try `np.where`:

```
data1['valid from date'] = np.where(conditions5, data1['Value Date'], '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data1['Valid From Date'] = np.where(data1['Payment Mode'] == '03', data1['Value Date'], '')
```